How to Update Windows Desktop Blazor MAUI App to an Older Version Using PackageManager?
I'm working on a Windows desktop application using Blazor MAUI. I'm using the PackageManager class to handle application updates. My current implementation works fine when updating to a newer version, but I'm facing issues when trying to update to an older version than the one that is already installed.
Here is the method I am currently using:
RegisterApplicationRestart(null, RestartFlags.NONE);

var deploymentOperation = packageManager.AddPackageAsync(packageUri, null, DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown);
var opCompletedEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

deploymentOperation.Completed = (depProgress, status) => opCompletedEvent.SetResult(true);
await opCompletedEvent.Task;

if (deploymentOperation.Status == AsyncStatus.Error)
{
    var deploymentResult = deploymentOperation.GetResults();
    _logger.LogError("Error installing update: {ErrorText}", deploymentResult.ErrorText);
    returnValue = 1;
}
else if (deploymentOperation.Status == AsyncStatus.Completed)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Update installation succeeded.");
}

When attempting to install an older version of the application than the currently installed version, the update fails. The PackageManager.AddPackageAsync operation does not succeed, and I receive an error indicating that a downgrade is not allowed.
How can I modify my update logic to allow for downgrading to an older version of the application using PackageManager? Are there any specific DeploymentOptions or additional steps I need to take to handle this scenario?
Additional Information:
The application is built using .NET MAUI for Windows.
The update packages are downloaded from a remote server.
I am using DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown in the update operation.
Any guidance or examples on handling downgrades would be greatly appreciated.

Do you use PackageManager? Have you tried remove first and then add it?

Yes, i tried it, but becuase it uninstalls the app, it does not continue with the execution of the rest of the code, so i have no way to install the new and restart it

This API does not support downgrade as it says downgrade is not allowed.

The scenairo is for self-service kiosk, so manually upgrade/downgrade is needed in case something goes wrong in the upgrade.

I am open for suggestions, if there are different APIs or approaches that will be able to help us in this scenario.

You can't downgrade on upgrade, and you can't remove your own package and keep running by APIs.

Yeah, so what would be possible alternative for kiosk on maui app? As I mentioned, open to any ideas.
